# How to return to parent activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have three Android `activity` A, B, C.

I am calling `B` activity from `A` activity:

```
public void onCreate(){

 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
}
```

In onSuccess of `B` activity I am using `Sharedpreference`:

```
protected void onSuccess(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
  /...../
  editor.apply()
}
```

Now I want to access the parameters of `sharedPreferences` in `A` activity class. In which method of Activity `A` will I get these parameters? `onSuccess`?. Activity `B` will also return to Activity `A` before accessing these parameters. How can i do that? I am newbie in `Android` development.

```
 #Edit
public void onCreate(){
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

SharedPreferences have App-Scope. So even if you save them into an activity, you can call them in every other activities of your app.

In each activity you can call this for saving some prefs:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("Key", "Value");
editor.putInt("Key2", Value(int));
editor.apply();
```

and, always from all activities, you can retrieve them by calling:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("Key", null);

if (restoredText != null) 
{
    int Key2= prefs.getInt("Key2", -1);
    /*if (selectionStart != -1)
    {
        //do Something
    }*/
}
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) you can find a good guide for it which explains nearly all you need to know :)

EDIT:

Ok, this image can help you understanding the Android life cycle:

[image: lifecycle]

Since you wanna go back from Activity B to Activity A you can avoid calling the `finish()` method; You can do the following:

Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Now, A activity will be the first in the backstack of the app below the B activity.

Activity B:

```
//Do your stuffs
finish();
```

now Activity B will be closed and A showed again.

If you want to finish the A Activity anyway, in B activity, instead of `finish();` you use an Intent again:

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

if you have to pass data back to activity A, in the A activity call the B using `startActivityForResult();`. [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) is the doc about it.

But if in B activity you only need to get sharedPref and use them in A activity, I suggest you to retrieve them directly from A activity, since they have App scope.

EDIT2:

You can access SharedPrefs in onCreate(), but only if the onCreate method is invoked after the sp are saved.

I suggest you to use the last method: call B activity with

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

and then call A with

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

you will have sharedPrefs in onCreate.

For any question, I'm still here :)

PS: remember to check **always** if sharedPrefs exists, using

```
if (sharedPref.contains("Key"))
{
     // dosomething
}
```

PPS: sharedPrefs are usually used for only settings, if you need to save more values, try having a look at [sugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/), an extremely easy database for your apps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After calling the activity `B` from `A` I want to return the cursor to activity `A` when everything is done from the side of activity `B`. And after return it to actvity `A` from `B` I want to use this Sharedpreference data.

Comment: @SnowClue so, just to know if i understood: you want to get sharedPref in Activity B and use them in Activity A?

Comment: Yes, I want to set value in `B` activity and use it into `A` Activity. I tried with above code (See the edit section). After putting debug point I found that the cursor reached first `A.onCreate().Finish()` than `B.onSuccess()`.

Comment: @SnowClue i edited, i hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Agree that sharedPref has AppScope but in which method of `A` activity I will get the set value from `B` activity ? I am sure that I can't get in `A.onCreate()` method.  What I am looking for:

Start A activity -> call B activity from A -> set value in shared pref in B activity -> return to A activity -> fetch the value from SetPref -> call C activity from A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88170/discussion-between-snowclue-and-pier-giorgio-misley).